OpenTelemetry tracing a request that involves REST and SQS
I have a Spring Boot 3 app that consists of multiple microservices, and I'm considering to use the OpenTelemetry agent. I have a flow where a user sends an http request to a gateway API, the request is placed in SQS, fetched by a listener, and then sent to another API. If I want to trace the request through, does the agent do this automatically, by somehow propagating the initial trace id through the SQS, and from there to the other API? Or do I need to capture the initial trace id and somehow pass it through SQS and over to the next endpoint? Could you show me how?
Thanks.

I don't see any automatic instrumentation (yet) available for SQS at https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/tree/main/instrumentation.
